# In Server 2019 control panel, the server shows with an asterisk - unknown device

Tags: windows-server-2019, devices

Single server small network and in the Control Panel, the server icon shows unknown:

[image]

Why would this happen - and what's the implication?  Clients connect OK, all seems OK, but it's nevertheless unnerving.

Only things attached is a monitor, bog standard keyboard,and two USB drives for backups.

Nothing in the error logs other than expected annoyance stuff Alerts that are safe to ignore - e.g. took 'x' seconds for this or that to complete.

Answer (score 0):

Found the issue. The Devices and Printers showed the error as being the server itself. Slogging through Error logs found errors on two specific dates that matched up with video driver updates.

As this is a CPU with onboard video, a wonky driver update made it show the server itself as erroring.

Found a newer driver from Dell. Installed it.

Holding breath deleted the device from Device Manager. Rebooted.

The error was gone and driver installed correctly.

I guess it makes sense that if it's an on CPU video, the whole device is flagged, but still...